# Is it safe to encrypt data using XOR along with CSPRNG seeded with a truly random number?

Tags: aes, algorithm-design, random-number-generator

I was wondering a couple of days ago whether I could reverse the normal encryption order to produce a good AES based cipher variant. The method is as follows:

Two users, Alice and Bob, each have a copy of a shared key they want to use for AES. They each also have one shared seed to use for the CSPRNG. For Alice to talk to Bob, she would use AES with her initial RNG seed and shared key to generate a block of random data. Subsequent random numbers are generated as follows:

```
r[0] = AES(key, ASeed);
r[1] = AES(key,AES(key,ASeed));
r[2] = AES(key,AES(key,AES(ASeed)));
etc
```

She would then XOR the results of her random number with the plaintext to get the ciphertext. Furthermore, when she sends the encrypted data to Bob, she also sends a sequence number in the clear, indicating how many random numbers need to be computed for Bob to decrypt the data.

Bob would do the same when he wanted to talk to Alice.

The only major flaw I see in this setup is the sequence number which is sent unencrypted. It needs to be, otherwise Bob will not be able to know which random number to XOR the ciphertext with to get the original plaintext. An attacker could deliberately change this sequence number to mess up Bob's decryption method. This is a source of DoS against Bob, who is then made to decrypt junk data.

However, Alice and Bob could agree on using a HMAC scheme to prevent someone without the key from sending a legit message. In this case, the plaintext is still exposed, but cannot be changed. The sequence number can also be a signal for an attacker about how the encrypted data is organized.

Anyone has any opinion on this? It is clearly inferior to the old method, Since it leaks info in the sequence number.

```
//good old AES
AES(key,data);
```

Comment: This is [Output Feedback Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Output_Feedback_.28OFB.29).

Comment: Is there any way to hide the sequence number? I don't see how, since Bob will need it to know which random number to use for decryption. Sequence numbers are used when communicating in fixed packets where packets may be lost, such as UDP.

Comment: If the attacker has the ability to intercept/change/suppress packages between Alice and Bob, he can shut down the connection anyway or just send any amount of randomness to Bob. Any way of cryptographic verification will also take some computation time, and thus the attacker can always keep Bob busy.

Comment: @tylo HMAC based packet verification can work very well against such kinds of attacks. Of course, you cannot prevent an attacker from delaying or stopping packets, but changes can be easily detected with little computational resources.

Comment: It seems I fail to understand your problem/question. In fact, it seems there isn't one.